# Excel Macro - Count a consecutive child list in a consecutive parent list

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

please help me to count a consecutive child list in a consecutive parent list.
I have a data table:
    -----<- A (column) -><- B (column) -><- C (column) ->
1 ----- aa --------------- aa ---------------- aa
2 ----- bb --------------- bb ---------------- bb
3 ----- aa ------------------------------------ aa
4 ----- aa
5 ----- bb
6 ----- bb
7 ----- aa
8 ----- aa
9 ----- aa
10 ---- bb
11 ---- aa
12 ---- bb

if i count list B in list A, returned result is 4.
if i count list C in list A, returned result is 2.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there a max number of rows on the depth off the B/C type columns?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much a brute force solution but will do the trick.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function PatternCount(PatternRange As Excel.Range, TargetRange As Excel.Range) As Integer
    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim oEndCell As Excel.Range
    Dim sTargetPattern As String
    Dim sPattern As String
    Dim iCount As Integer

    sTargetPattern = RangeSignature(PatternRange)

    For Each oCell In TargetRange
        Set oEndCell = oCell.Offset(RowOffset:=PatternRange.Count - 1)
        sPattern = RangeSignature(Range(oCell, oEndCell))

        If sPattern = sTargetPattern Then iCount = iCount + 1
    Next oCell

    PatternCount = iCount

    Set oCell = Nothing
    Set oEndCell = Nothing
End Function

Private Function RangeSignature(TargetRange As Excel.Range) As String
    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim sPattern As String

    For Each oCell In TargetRange.Cells
        sPattern = sPattern & oCell.Value & "|"
    Next oCell

    RangeSignature = sPattern

    Set oCell = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Nice! Be aware that this will count overlapping occurrences. So if looking for `a|b|a|b` in `a|b|a|b|a|b|a|b|a|b|a|b`, `PatternCount` will return 5, not 3 as you may (or may not) expect.